# Parallax effect for the pageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `pageViewController` - I would like to add a scrollview with an image view behind it and while I scroll the pages in my `pageViewController` - the background should scroll in the same direction but with a lower see. I use `auto-layout` in storyboards:

so I add the pageViewController:

```
pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                                 navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                                                               options:nil];
pageController.delegate = self;
pageController.dataSource = self;
[self addChildViewController:pageController];

CGRect pageFrame = self.view.frame;
pageFrame.origin.y += 50.f;
pageFrame.size.height -= 50.f;
pageController.view.frame = pageFrame;
pageController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:pageController.view];
```

get it's scrollview:

```
for (UIView *possibleScrollView in pageController.view.subviews) {
    if ([possibleScrollView isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {
        ((UIScrollView *)possibleScrollView).delegate = self;
    }
}
```

and listening for its delegate:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"%f", scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    [parlaxScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x * .2f, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:NO];
}
```

And here I have some confusing results when I scrolling to the second page:

```
378.500000
386.500000
403.500000
419.000000
448.000000
469.000000
...
747.000000
750.000000
375.000000 ///!!!!!THE CONTENT OFFSET RETURNED TO THE INITIAL VALUE!!!!!
```

Why does my content view offset reset? Wha't wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

5 years later, sorry for the delay 
Maybe other people will still have the same issue.

You are not supposed to change the delegate of the page view controller's scroll view. It can break its normal behaviour.

Instead, you can:

1. Add a pan gesture to the page view controller's view:

   ```
   let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panRecognized(gesture:)))
   view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
   panGesture.delegate = self
   ```
2. Add the new function in order to know how the view is being scrolled.

   ```
   @objc func panRecognized(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
       // Do whatever you need with the gesture.translation(in: view)
   }
   ```
3. Declare your ViewController as `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.
4. Implement this function:

   ```
   func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
       return true
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to keep track of which page is currently being displayed and add the width to the content offset.

something like this:
let currentPage:Int

Comment: I solved the issue by using SwipeView library - thx for your suggestions